# Adding points upon giving a rank

Tags: php, mysql

Right so i have a promotion button setup. Every promotion someone receives it gives them earning points to their profile, But every rank has different points depending on how high it is or low it is. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to get the points to scale with their ranks. My database column for it is known as: rank and the ranks are known as numbers in the database in which when it shows externally they all have a name from a function.  So ie; Rank 1, 2, 3, 4 would equal say Noob, Member, Elite, God. Anyway if you can help me find out where my error is that would be great, kinda new to php. The issue I'm having is that the points are not being given to the person. They get promoted fine but no points.

**promote.php**

```
    <?php include_once('../classes/check.class.php'); ?>
<?php  include('../config/db.php'); ?>
<?php include('functionsprom.php'); ?>
<?php if( protectThis("1, 2, 3") ) : ?>
<?php

 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $date = date('d M y');
 $prom = promote;
 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE players SET date='$date', rank = rank + 1, exp = exp + '$prom' WHERE id=$id", $db1)
 or die(mysql_error()); 

    require_once("../config/logdb.php");
 include('../logs.php');
 write_mysql_log($promote, $db);


 header("Location: ../home.php");
 }
 else
 {
 header("Location: home.php");
 }

?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**functionsprom.php**

```
    <?php
include('functionsrank.php');
mysql_select_db('pts_player');

$rank = "SELECT rank FROM players WHERE id = $id";

    function promote($rank) {
    if($rank == 1):
    $prom = 0;
    elseif($rank == 2):
    $prom = 0;
    elseif($rank == 3):
    $prom = 0;
    elseif($rank == 4 ):
    $prom = 10;
    elseif($rank == 5):
    $prom = 20;
    elseif($rank == 6):
    $prom = 30;
    elseif($rank == 7):
    $prom = 45;
    elseif($rank == 8):
    $prom = 45;
    elseif($rank == 9):
    $prom = 55;
    elseif($rank == 10):
    $prom = 60;
    elseif($rank == 11):
    $prom = 75;
    elseif($rank == 12):
    $prom = 75;
    elseif($rank == 13):
    $prom = 0;
    elseif($rank == 14):
    $prom = 0;
    elseif($rank == 15):
    $prom = 100;
    elseif($rank == 16):
    $prom = 200;
    elseif($rank == 17):
    $prom = 400;
    elseif($rank == 18):
    $prom = 600;
    elseif($rank == 19):
    $prom = 800;
    elseif($rank == 20):
    $prom = 900;
    elseif($rank == 21):
    $prom = 1000;
    elseif($rank == 22):
    $prom = 1200;
    elseif($rank == 23):
    $prom = 1400;
    elseif($rank == 24):
    $prom = 0;
    endif;
    return $rank;
    }
?>
```

Comment: So... Are you having a error or do you not know how to achieve the desired functionality? - If you are having a error please include the error and show us that you've done at least some debugging. - If it's the other case then I'm afraid SO is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: @Epodax Well the issue is, is that its not giving the actual points. It promotes them easily but no points are being given to them.

Comment: Try actually executing the SQL Query rather than just putting it into a string variable in `functionsprom.php`. Then try returning the `$prom` and not the `$rank` at the end of `functionsprom.php`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Same thing happened, it promoted but no points were given.

Comment: I spotted another woops see previous comment

Comment: Also you are executing a function on this line `$prom = promote;` so it shoudl read `$prom = promote($SOME_VARIABLE);`

Comment: Man that code needs a REFACTOR, its some of the worst `spagettii code` I have seen in many a year.